# Fundamental group of the torus using the edge group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm following the notes of Lackenby to study Algebraic Topology and he gives the prove of the fundamental group of the circle using the edge group.
Since I already know the triangulation of the torus I was trying to prove that its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know how to start.
Can anyone give me a hint, please?

Comment: I'm using the abstract simplicial complex with nine vertices as the triangulation of the torus

Comment: You can try to write down the matrices representing  the differentials (since they are maps from and to free abelian groups with basis your simplices)  and obtain their kernels and images.